# linq to sql "into" conditional with select

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have an Invoice class that I want to have multiple Packages, but I only want those Packages to be there if they have been shipped later than the last record in Record.  I've been using "into" to get the other groups into the object, but I'm struggling with joining only the specific packages.

```
from invoice in invoices
join item in InvoiceItems on invoice.InvoiceId equals item.InvoiceId into items // Gives the item collection
join package in packages on invoice.InvoiceId equals package.InvoiceId // only want the packages that satisfy the condition...
where package.ShipDate > (subquery)
```

This query would work, except I would get multiple of the same invoices if there are multiple packages.  If I add "into packages" on the end of the join, I don't know how to only get the packages that satisfy the second condition.

The subquery is:

```
(from lastSentRecord in records
where lastSentRecord.InvoiceID == invoice.InvoiceID
orderby lastSentRecord.SendDateTime descending
select lastSentRecord.SendDateTime ?? new DateTime()).First()
```

The important part of the class structure is

```
Invoice --- InvoiceID
Package --- InvoiceID, ShipDate
Record --- InvoiceID, SendDateTime, EmailType
```

Comment: Where does `Record` come in? In particular, does that depend on `invoice`?

Comment: can you provide the structure of your datasets?

Comment: @JonSkeet The record is a notification saying that we need to send out an e-mail.  It has InvoiceID, EmailType, SentDate.  I'll add the subquery to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work-around, I did the following:

```
from invoice in invoices
join packge in packages on invoice.InvoiceId equals package.InvoiceId into packages
where (from package in packages
       where package.InvoiceId == invoice.InvoiceId
       where package.ShipDate > timeSent
       select 1).Any()
select new {packages.Where(p => p.ShipDate > timeSent)}
```

It gets the job done, but I'd like to do it a better way.  I'll leave this open for a bit longer to see if anyone has answers, then I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your make them two separate queries and then satisfy the second condition (probably calling the second one first so that you can create the variable for the where). The article below shows you how you could do that by doing it in the select statement.

[This would also solve your problem](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/09/24/nested-selects-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Comment: I know how to use separate queries.  I'm not sure how they would apply in this situation.